# Is there a quicker way to look up all image, audio and video file types in both client and server side

Tags: php, javascript

Below I have 3 javascript functions which checks for a legitimate file extension for their files. The problem is that if I am doing it the way I am implementing it, I will have a very large case statement for each function stating which file extensions are legitmate to use. So what my question is that except doing

```
`case:jpeg: 
case:jpg:
case:png`
```

and etc. Is there a quick way to create a case statment that checks for all legitimate image file extension types, all legitimate video file extension types and all legitimate audio file extension types?

Below is the 3 javascript functions I am currently using to validate file extension types for images, videos and audio:

IMAGE:

```
   function imageValidation(imageuploadform) {

        var val = $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
            case 'gif':
            case 'jpg': 
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'pjpeg':
            case 'png':
                 return true;

            case '':
                $(imageuploadform).find(".fileImage").val();
                alert("To upload an image, please select an Image File");
                return false;

            default:
                alert("To upload an image, please select a valild file extension.");
                return false;

        }

        return false;

}
```

VIDEO:

```
function videoValidation(videouploadform) {

    var val = $(videouploadform).find(".fileVideo").val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'mpg':
        case 'mov': 
        case 'wmv':
        case 'rm':
        case '3g2':
        case '3gp':
        case 'm2v':
        case 'm4v':
             return true;

        case '':
            $(videouploadform).find(".fileVideo").val();
            alert("To upload an video, please select an Video File");
            return false;

        default:
            alert("To upload an video, please select a valild file extension.");
            return false;

    }

    return false;

}
```

AUDIO:

```
  function audioValidation(audiouploadform) {

        var val = $(audiouploadform).find(".fileAudio").val();
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
            case 'wav':
            case 'aif': 
            case 'mp3':
            case 'mid':
                 return true;

            case '':
                $(audiouploadform).find(".fileAudio").val();
                alert("To upload an audio, please select an Audio File");
                return false;

            default:
                alert("To upload an audio, please select a valild file extension.");
                return false;

        }

        return false;


}
```

Also does anyone know what is the php equivalent on being able to check all image file types, video file types and audio file types as that I will need to do server side validation as well for file types. I just want to know if there is a quicker way than just listing all of the possible image, video and audio file types.

Comment: Never trust a file extension. On the server you should be checking the MIME type of the file. Anybody can change the extension.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type - MIME types are determined using file signatures, and are far more accurate. Text files would be `text/plain`, etc.

Comment: @MitchDempsey even MIME types are not trustworthy, especially for some files, but I do agree with your original assertion that extensions are not trustworthy.

Comment: OK so if I go by using MIME for image, video and audio, how can this be implemented in the code above? for example how can image type MIME in the image validation function above?

Comment: On the client side, it's probably easiest to check the extension. But once it gets to the server, you should use the MIME type to verify.

Comment: In order to check the MIME type on the client side, you would probably need to have some flash/java uploader

Comment: I do use an ajax uploader, could that work?

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkFileExtension(AcceptableFileNamesRegex, fileName){
  var pattern = AcceptableFileNamesRegex;
  return pattern.test(fileName);
}

var regex = /wav|aif|mp3|mid/

checkFileExtension(regex, "myWav.wav")
```

Comment: but wouldn't this mean for var regex I need to store like 20-30 different file types before doing the check on the file extension?

Comment: It is the same as using the case but there is much less code and you don't use several javascript funcitons to parse the string several times. Also MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions), which is just to tell what type of data is being transfered. Also based on your example it would be 17 different file extensions.

Comment: so is there no shorter way of actually writing the code to check for all file types for images, audio and video?

Comment: This javascript function is much shorter than the original 3 other functions. Just reuse the same function in each place that you need it and redefine the AcceptableFileNamesRegex param in each place. Saves you like 40+ lines

Comment: What I meant is do I have to type in each file extension individually, is there no short way where it checks for all image file extension types for example. Do I have to write /jpg/jpeg/tiff/png/gif etc

Comment: What about extensions that can be either Video or Audio such as MP4?